# Gdb with emacs and F*

Tags: emacs, gdb, fstar, fstar-mode

I would like to debug simple F* program using Emacs fstar-mode and gdb. At the very end of the wiki of fstar-mode https://github.com/FStarLang/fstar-mode.el is information:

```
The fstar-gdb command (M-x) attaches GDB to the current F* process and launches Emacs' GDB-mi interface
```

with no further explanation.

When in Emacs (lets assume I am editing Test.fst file) I invoke `fstar-gdb` command and proceed to `gdb` console I am trying to use commands `file Test` and `run`. They are working correctly, however `break 3` (or any other line) says that it failed to find line 3 in `main.c` (obviously).

How do I use `gdb` with F*?

Comment: Let's narrow down where the error occurs. If you run gdb from a shell window instead of emacs, do you still get the error when you type `break 3`?

Comment: Unfortunately the output is: `(gdb) break 3

>>> Breakpoint 1 at 0x5555555c6790: file main.c, line 3.
(gdb) run

>>> Starting program: /home/kicjow/Desktop/msc-neuralnet-verification/fstar-test/Test.exe 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffddb8) at main.c:32
32 main.c: No such file or directory.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fstar-gdb command is intended to the debug F* compiler itself, not programs compiled with F*.

For F* programs, the best would likely be:

- ocamldebug if you're using the byte-compiler
- the usual procedure for GDB debugging of OCaml programs (see https://ocaml.org/meetings/ocaml/2012/slides/oud2012-paper5-slides.pdf; this is because most F* programs are extracted to OCaml before being compiled).
- the usual procedure for debugging GDB debugging of C programs if you're using Low*.